# How to aggregate the prediction of StratifiedKFold split for more than one classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-fold

This is my code:

```
fold = StratifiedKFold(10, shuffle= True, random_state=42)
score = []
cat_prediction = []
lgbm_prediction = []
forest_prediction = []
rgb_prediction = []
oldList = []
for train_s, test_s in tqdm(fold.split(X, Y)):
    
    xtrain, ytrain = X.iloc[train_s], Y.iloc[train_s]
    xtest, ytest = X.iloc[test_s], Y.iloc[test_s]   
    
    #xtrain, ytrain = df.drop("Response", 1).iloc[train_s], df.Response.iloc[train_s]
    #xtest, ytest = df.drop("Response", 1).iloc[test_s], df.Response.iloc[test_s]
    model = RGFClassifier(algorithm="RGF_Sib", test_interval=100, normalize = True)
    model.fit(df.drop("Response", 1), df.Response)
    score.append(f1_score(ytest, model.predict(xtest)))
    rgb_prediction.append(model.predict(tt))
    
    model = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight = class_weight)
    model.fit(df.drop("Response", 1), df.Response)
    score.append(f1_score(ytest, model.predict(xtest)))
    forest_prediction.append(model.predict(tt))
    
    model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations= 400, class_weights = class_weight, silent= True)
    model.fit(df.drop("Response", 1), df.Response)
    score.append(f1_score(ytest, model.predict(xtest)))
    cat_prediction.append(model.predict(tt))
    
    model = LGBMClassifier(class_weight = class_weight)
    model.fit(df.drop("Response", 1), df.Response)
    score.append(f1_score(ytest, model.predict(xtest)))
    lgbm_prediction.append(model.predict(tt))
```

I want to aggregate the scores to make a blend of the different models.
I tried

```
(cat_prediction + lgbm_prediction + forest_prediction + rgb_prediction)/4
```

and

```
(np.mean(cat_prediction , 0) + np.mean(lgbm_prediction, 0) + np.mean(forest_prediction , 0) + np.mean(rgb_prediction, 0))/4
```

But the result are not as desired.
How do I achieve this?

Comment: This is classification, so taking mean will give you decimal points, use mode instead.

Comment: You can also use `VotingClassifier()` from Scikit-Learn inside that stratified loop, to shorten the code.

Comment: I just used VotingClassifier, it does well but not even upto the performance of a single classifier evem when I used 'voting_method= soft'.

Comment: Yeah, it won't give you that good results. Models like LightGBM or Catboost are powerful. They don't usually require any other model's support. Just use one model like LightGBM, train it with early stopping and tune it with Optuna. It will give you better results. There is need of using 4 models unless you are participating on Kaggle.

Comment: Helpful. I am paticipating in a Zindi hackathon.